# Django form save error after is_valid return true

Tags: django, django-forms

What is the best practice to handle the errors on `form.save()`? For example email unique check will be done in save on database level, not on `is_valid()`.

```
def user_registration(request):
    from accounts.forms import UserRegistrationForm
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if not form.is_valid():
        return {
            'errors': form.errors.as_json(escape_html=False)
        }
    ### This can still return error, how to handle it? try catch?
    user = form.save()
    return {
        'user': user.id,
    }
```

Comment: Why is the uniqueness check being done only in the database? Why haven't you defined `unique=True` on the email field in the model itself? If you had then it would be checked as part of the form validation.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, there should be `clean_email` method on the form class that checks if the email already exists. `save` method should be called after all the validation is done.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the email before reaching the form validation.  You can do something like

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     email = request.POST.get("email")
     if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
         form.add_error("email","Email exists")

     if not form.is_valid():
         return {
             'errors': form.errors.as_json(escape_html=False)
         }
     user = form.save()
```